# Normalizing the name of JSON name

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the ember-data to get all my events on my route api: `/api/events`, the problem is that the JSON that returns does not comply with the request by Ember, is there anything I can do to fix it?

This is my code:

Adapter and Serializer:

```
SiteApp.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
SiteApp.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

EventModel:

```
SiteApp.Event = DS.Model.extend({
  description : DS.attr(),
  name        : DS.attr().
  type        : DS.attr()
});
```

And in the Route i have the `this.store.findAll('event');`

The JSON is like this:

```
{
  data: [{
    _id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f333",
    attributes: {
      description: "test",
      name: "name",
      is_active: false
    },
    type: "events"
  }]
}
```

Which will work if i change the "data" for "event", but i can't, that's not a option.

Is possible resolve with other way?

Comment: `modelNameFromPayloadKey`?

Comment: When you say you can't change `data` to `event` are you talking about on the server? Because you can [change it on the client](http://jsfiddle.net/os962hq7/) by creating a new object and assigning `data`'s value to a new obj.

Comment: Yes, i can't change the response in the server, so i need change in the client, that's possible?

Comment: I will search for this modelNameFromPayloadKey @torazaburo

Comment: yep, this works @torazaburo, is possible to get the value of type, and assign the new payload, in the RESTSerializer??

Comment: I'm not too much of an expert on the JSON API, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change the name of the key on that object, but you can create a new object with an `event` property and assign the value of `data` to that property:

```
var newobj = {};
newobj.event = obj.data;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/os962hq7/)

Comment: Are you sure? I can't use some ember build in function to fix this?

Comment: I don't use ember so I don't know. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: I don't have access to the server, so i can't use it :/

Comment: No, you do this on the client side. You receive the JSON, parse it: `var obj = JSON.parse(json)` and then do what I suggest in the answer.